# How do you use a button click function to convert an [PHAsset] to PHAsset in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, phasset

```
public func nohanaImagePicker(_ picker: NohanaImagePickerController, didFinishPickingPhotoKitAssets pickedAssts: [PHAsset])
{
    print("Completed\n\tpickedAssets = \(pickedAssts)")
    self.getAssetThumbnail(asset: pickedAssts)
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.ImageCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Anyone can u explain how to convert the [PHAsset] value to PHAsset

Comment: its an array `[PHAsset]` fetech the first or 0th index for indiviual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[PHAsset]` is an array of `PHAsset` objects. You can pick the first object of the array like this.

```
let phAsset = pickedAssts.first
```

Comment: func getAssetThumbnail(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
    
    option.version = .original
        option.isSynchronous = true
        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
            thumbnail = result!
        })
        return thumbnail
    }

Comment: Please edit your question and update there ... Very difficult to understand the code here in comments.